# Rails 6: strongly typing raw SQL Query returning array type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

For reasons that are not really relevant to the question, I've had to construct a fairly complex query manually rather than using ActiveRecord. This query currently returns a PostgreSQL array data type and I'm trying to see if I can map it to more useful Ruby types than what Rails is providing by default.

Pseudo-code below:

```sql
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(u.id) AS awesome_data
FROM u
GROUP BY condition
```

```rb
records = []
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
      ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [
                                query,
        # parameters
                              ])
      ).each do |record|
        records << record
      end
```

This query works fine and returns what I would expect, but the type of the `awesome_data` column comes back as `string` and contains values like `{1,2,3,4}`.

Couple of questions:

- Is there any way to make Rails understand that the column is an array type and to parse it as an array?
- Is there a utility method that will parse this to an array of integers for me?
- Do I have to parse this value myself?

Restrictions:

We have to assume that its necessary to query the database in this fashion and not go through ActiveRecord.

Env: Rails 6.1, Ruby 3.2 and PostgreSQL 12

Comment: You can create the query as a database view then use the database view as the basis of an ActiveRecord model and get all the AR goodies. You'll just need to add a column that can serve as a primary key.

Comment: "{1,2,3,4}"[1...-1].split(",").map(&:to_i) #=> [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Result`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) has [`cast_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L94-L118) method (it uses `deserialize` under the hood)

```rb
query = <~SQL
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(u.id) AS awesome_data
  FROM u
  GROUP BY condition
SQL
```

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query).cast_values.flatten
# => [1, 2, 3, 4] # Ruby array of integers
```

If you want sanitize SQL, don't use `send` — call sanitize method directly

These methods are not private but [public](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html)

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql([query])
```

You can also use `Arel` to generate sanitized SQL

```rb
u = Arel::Table.new('u')

query =
  u.project(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ARRAY_AGG', [u[:id]]).as('awesome_data'))
   .group('condition')
   .to_sql
```

Comment: *"If you want sanitize SQL, don't use send — call sanitize method directly"* or don't use RAW sql use `Arel`?

Comment: Based on my question where there is only one column in the result, this is the appropriate answer, but I should say that `cast_values` does seem to remove the dictionary access and just returns an array with all the columns indexed by number. If you have multiple columns in the result that becomes tricky. What I found works for me is the following: `result.column_types['column_name'].deserialize(row['column_name'])`

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out that `sanitize_sql_array` is not a private method. That cleaned up the code quite a bit.